# select value from search drop down not working in selenium

Tags: selenium, select

[image: front end source code]

**My code:**

```
 try
    {
        WebElement pdtSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMainContent_ItemSearchUC_tbcBase_pnlGeneral_lstProductTypes"));
        Select drppdttype = new Select(pdtSelectElement);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

         js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');",pdtSelectElement);
       //drppdttype.selectByVisibleText("1 bowl inset sink with drainer");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      // drppdttype.selectByValue("10924|00000");          
       drppdttype.selectByIndex(5);    

        System.out.println("product type selected");
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("product type not selected");
    }
```

still my code is not working even though i used all the select options

Comment: did you check what `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait` does? why are you setting it several times to the same value, and also after you already searched for element? look up explicit wait instead and wait explicitly for element `By.id("ctl00_cphMainContent_ItemSearchUC_tbcBase_pnlGeneral_lstProductTypes")` to be visible, instead of `driver.findElement`. Most likely you are just not waiting for it

Comment: what is the exception, and why wait of 5 minutes

Comment: @KirilS. Used xpath to click the element after highlighting the drop down. stil selectByIndex and visibletext did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is actually working for me. 
I am not what issue you are facing. Can yo